# Import updating CSV into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I'm looking for a simple solution (beginner to SQL) to allow the import of data from my .csv file to my SQL DB.

I have a third party program that is updating my .csv file every 30 seconds and I want to put that updating information into my SQL DB. I tried the importing & exporting wizard but it didn't work due to the .csv file being utilized by the other third party program.

Getting the information into the SQL DB doesn't need to be in real time it could just retrieve all the information when opening a saved sql query file.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't you have any other languages involved in sending data to and from the database?

Comment: At the moment nothing is going into the database. But that's what I want to happen. The .csv file is populating and I want to transfer that information to the DB

Answer (score 0):

OPENROWSET is the simplest one if you get that working in your env for CSV file. i have seen lot of issues with what OS, and what version of MS office installed with 32bit or 64 bit.

but bit more work and you will be all set with creating a small SSIS package to import that CSV in to table. execute that SSIS using SQL JOB at desired interval. later if you needed more complex insert/update you can always modify the package.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of [producer consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) where one process is writing data and another one is reading it.

Whatever you do you need to setup some kind of lock on this file that process can check if file is available for reading/writing.  If import/export wizard had issues with concurrency then probably other processes will also.

Another option is to always create new file to write into and have reader process to always read from the newest one and delete it after processing.

One more thing you’ll have to take care of is reading from same file multiple times. You need some way to mark the records that have already been read so these are not inserted twice.

All of the above is needed if this needs to be a fully automated and unattended process.

If not you can just manually create a copy of CSV file and then use import/export wizard to import the data.

Here is another resource you can check out for importing CSV into SQL Server

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/